# While loop doesn't read condition

Tags: python, loops, while-loop

I'm trying to make a program that will stop when it gets 5 prime numbers from a range. 
I've completed most of the program except the part where it is supposed to stop after it gets 5 numbers. 
I've added a condition for it to stop, once the counter reaches 5 but it does not stop and continues to list all the numbers in the range.
Here is code I have:

```
condition = 0
while condition < 5:
  for numbers in range(2,20):
      for divisor in range(2,numbers):
        if (numbers % divisor) == 0:
          break
      else:
        print(numbers)
        condition +=1
```

The condition+=1 never goes through and it lists all the prime numbers from 1 to 20 even though I just want the first 5.

I've tried spacing options with the "condition +=1" but it still does not work

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: You're always processing all numbers in range 2 to 20, and you're doing all that 5 times… The entire contents of the `while` block run to completion, again and again, until the `while` condition is reached…

Comment: So, you're saying to move the "condiiton +=1" out more?

Comment: If you want to find the first 5 numbers in the range 2 to 20 (which, BTW, is a redundant condition; you simply want to find the first 5 primes, period), then you need to **`break` your `for .. in` loop after `condition` has reached `5`.** You don't need the wrapping `while` at all.

Comment: Will the `break` not skip the `else` in the for loop?

Comment: @Fourier Yes, that's the point. The `else` is only executed *if* no `break` occurred.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`While` is out of `for` loop, so cannot work obviously. A simple solution is to check required condition later:

```
for numbers in range(2,20):
  for divisor in range(2,numbers):
    if (numbers % divisor) == 0:
      break
  else:
    print(numbers)
    condition +=1
    if condition >=5:
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the *real* problem you are having is that you have written bad code. A much better approach to this problem is to isolate as many pieces as possible.

for example:

```
def is_prime(x):
    "return true if x is prime, otherwise false"
    # implement me!
    return True

def get_first_n_primes_less_than_y(n, y):

    number = 2
    condition = 0

    while condition != n and number < y:
       if is_prime(number):
           print(number)
           condition += 1

       number += 1

get_first_n_primes(5, 20)
```

The above code, with some tweaking can perform the same task. However, code like this is much simpler to debug and reason about because we have isolated chunks of code (is_prime, has nothing to do with the while loop)

Answer (score 0):

```
num_results = 5
counter = 0


range_start = 2
range_end = 20

# iterate range
for number in range (range_start, range_end):

    # iterate divisors
    for divisor in range (2, number):

        # check division
        if (number % divisor) == 0:
            break
        else:
            print ("%s is a prime number" % number)
            counter += 1
            break

        # check if number of results has been reached
        if counter == num_results:
            break
    # check if number of results has been reached
    if counter == num_results:
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you need to run the entire content of the while block before you test the condition again.

Here is a way around

```py
condition = 0
numbers=2
while condition < 5 and numbers < 20:
    for divisor in range(2,numbers):
        if (numbers % divisor) == 0:
            break
    else:
        print(numbers)
        condition +=1
    numbers+=1
```